# Determine if the set of vectors $\{[-1, 3, 1], [2, 1, 4]\}$ is a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that the vectors span.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I recognize that this question is essentially identical to [Determine whether the set of vectors is a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$that the vectors span](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2141595/971909) posted by user K Split X; their question comes from a modified version of Question 29 on Chapter 1.6 on John B. Fraleigh and Raymond A. Beauregard's Linear Algebra textbook. Upon reviewing their question, I have made a solution attempt at the problem but have failed to reach the answer provided by the textbook; I would like to know why.

I determined that the above set of vectors *should* form a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that the vectors span; the textbook states otherwise.

My reasoning is as follows:

According to Beauregard, given an $m$ $\times$ $n$ matrix $A$, the following are equivalent:

1. Each consistent system $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ has a unique solution
2. The reduced row-echelon form of $A$ consists of the $n$ $\times$ $n$ identity matrix followed by $m-n$ rows of zeros
3. The column vectors of $A$ form a basis for the column space of $A$

Thus, I concluded that, given $m$ row vectors of dimensions $1$ $\times$ $n$, the set of vectors form a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$that the vectors span if and only if the matrix A formed by the transposes of the set of vectors can be row-reduced into the $m$ $\times$ $m$ identity matrix followed by $n-m$ rows of zeros.

Because matrix A = $\begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\3&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix}$ can be reduced into $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, the above statement is satisfied and the column vectors of $A$ form a basis for the column space of $A$. Since the column vectors of $A$ form a basis for the column space of $A$, the set of vectors $\{[-1, 3, 1], [2, 1, 4]\}$ is a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that the vectors span.

The textbook states that the set of vectors is not a basis. May someone enlighten me as to where I have made a mistake? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's just an error in the textbook, your reasoning is solid. Also the Author's names are John B. Fraleigh and Raymond A. Beauregard, which you seem to have combined into a single person Francis Beauregard.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks for the correction.